# Where can I find a list of Worklight Error Codes

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

Where can I find a list of the possible error codes for the various sections of Worklight?

Specifically, when I'm calling WL.JSONStore.findAll() my onFailure callback is being called and the error code is -50. I can't find this number anywhere in the code nor in the Worklight documentation, or on the web so far.

I've seen references to worklight.js having it, but it is not there. Ditto for WLResponse.h and WLFailResponse.h.

Comment: There is a WL.App.getErrorMessage(e) that prints out the error message for an exception. However, when I use it (running in the iOS simulator) it simply prints out -50, which doesn't help me.

Comment: [WL.JSONStore.getErrorMessage](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_geterrormessage.html) should print JSONStore error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of error codes is in the [JSONStore Documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_class_wl_jsonstore.html). Search for `List of error codes`.

Regarding the specific error code you mentioned: `-50` (`"PERSISTENT_STORE_NOT_OPEN"`) means JSONStore is closed, try calling [WL.JSONStore.init](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_init.html) first.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. However, when I search the documentation at http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_ibm_worklight_client_side_api_.html using "List of error codes" I don't find the documentation. I'm not sure what documentation you're referring to. I'm glad it exists. Please point me (and other readers) to it. Thanks!!!

Comment: In my answer above you can click on 'JSONStore Documentation' and it will take you to the right page, or you can click on 'WL.JSONStore' in the link you just shared.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. I don't know why it wasn't showing up in my searches, but I really appreciate you pointing me to it.